# Dax Switch Function 3rd value skipping

Tags: powerbi, dax

I use power bi Version: 2.112.603.0 64-bit (December 2022).In this version when im writing dax measure with switch function after giving the second result with the comma its asking third result.Its skipping 3 rd Value.What Im doing wrong here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The ([switch function](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dax/switch-function-dax)) has a minimum of 3 parameters that are Expression, Value, Result. It is in this situation like the IF function. But you can also add as many as you want other Value, Result pairs, in this case is more similar to the Case When statement.
To come back to your example, you could add other hasonevalue functions and the respective Result value and as last Parameter the else Value (if no Value is matched).